# How do I update joined entity inside an embedded entity with query builder?

Tags: typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have 3 entities, `A`, `B`, and `C`.
`B` is an embedded entity in `A`, and `B` also has OneToOne relation with `C`
I want to find `A` entity by its ID, and update a field in the related `C` entity in the same query.

```
@Entity()
export class TestEntityA extends DBBaseEntity() {
  @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
  public readonly aValue!: string

  @Column(() => TestEntityB)
  public readonly b!: TestEntityB
}

export class TestEntityB {
  @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
  public readonly bValue!: string

  @OneToOne(() => TestEntityC)
  @JoinColumn()
  public readonly c!: TestEntityC
}

@Entity()
export class TestEntityC extends DBBaseEntity() {
  @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
  public readonly cValue!: string
}
```

```
A
+---------+
| id      |
| a_value |      C
| b_value |      +---------+
| c_id ---|----> | id      |
+---------+      | c_value |
                 +---------+`
```

This is the basic query I worked with:

```
await this.testEntityARepo
  .createQueryBuilder('a')
  .update()
  .set({
    aValue: 'test_a',
    b: {
      bValue: 'test_b',
      c: {
        cValue: 'test_c',
      },
    },
  })
  .where(`id = :id`, { id: 1 })
  .execute()
```

The update of `aValue` and `bValue` worked as expected, but when I tried to update `cValue`
I am getting this error as expected

```
Property "b.c.cValue" was not found in "TestEntityA". Make sure your query is correct.
```

I have tried to join the table in many ways with `.joinLeft`, `.innerJoin`, `.innerJoinAndSelect`, `.andWhere` and more. But none of them worked.
What is the right way to do this?
Thank you